# Insert SQL Dataset into Tab control in Windows Form

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a simple SQL compact database I added to my project.
I am reading from "Head First C#" and the first program creates a database for contact info.
The book then says to drag the data source onto the form and it will create some data controls in the form automatically.

I tried doing this, but I am using a tab control with multiple tabs and when I drag the dataset onto the form, it erases the tab control.
I want my program to be able to modify the database only from one tab, I have other tabs for other things.

Any ideas on how to insert the dataset into a tab page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, go to the Data Source Explorer and right click on the table name you would like to drag and drop into the form.

Choose copy and then click on the tab page you want it inside and then paste it inside using Ctrl+v or right click on it and choose paste.

Sorry, after playing around with it a lot more, I was able to get it inside the tab.

Comment: No reason to apologize. Posting your own answer is a sign you used the site correctly :)